# Avoiding collision between particles and collider in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an arbitrarily large number of things shooting particle systems at each other. I want the particles to hit the targets but not the origin objects. Is it possible to either:

- Use `IgnoreCollision` between a ParticleSystem and a Collider
- Define new collision layers at runtime

Or is there some sneaky way of solving this I haven't considered?

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if the object you are colliding with is the same as your origin object so assign your origin game object to the origin variable of this script via inspector and then in collision check if the object you hit is the same , if it is not then you didn't hitter the origin

```
  Public GameObject origin;
 void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other) {          
     if(other.GetInstanceID() != origin.GetInstanceID())
         DoSomething();
              }
```

Comment: While this works for some cases, OnParticleCollision is only called after the actual physical collision and bounce takes place, which makes it impossible to fire out of an object since it never reaches the destination

Comment: you say now you check for collisions in your code and your problem is ignoring it in some cases , so how you check collisions your code

Comment: I do use OnParticleCollision for game logic. :) But the physical handling of the collision-- whether things pass through other things-- is a part of Unity, and I don't know how to influence that from my code.

Comment: the best way is to attach your particle to a gameobject and add a collider for your game object and use `OnCollisionEnter` instead

Answer (score 0):

Best advice I can give you it is to check for self-collisions and log a warning about who's doing it. Then it's a matter of fiddling colliders and particle spawners such that said collisions don't occur.

There doesn't appear to be any code-side way of telling the particle system collisions module to ignore certain colliders, unfortunately.

If absolutely all else fails you could possibly rejig things to work with Particle Trigger volumes instead? As workarounds go though that's probably a massive pain the arse; you'd have to control the 'collidable' set of shapes manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the **collides with** value of the **Collision** module at runtime you need to define a [Layermask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) and use the following code:

```
var particleCollision = yourParticleSystemComponent.collision;
particleCollision.collidesWith = layermask;
```

I believe that you can't use `IgnoreCollision` between a ParticleSystem and a Collider.